# Confusing comments from Drake in Uncharted: Drake's Fortune

Tags: uncharted

During the introductory cutscene from *Uncharted: Drake's Fortune*, there is a confusing exchange between Nathan and Elena. Nathan says the following:

> Nathan: Well, history can be wrong, you know. For example, you can't defile an empty coffin.

I don't understand how these two things are related. Why is it that history can be wrong when you cant defile an empty coffin?

Comment: Its from the intro cutscene of the game:Nathan gives the example to Elena that you cant defile an empty coffin .What this have to do that hystory can be wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dialogue is a bit clunky, but Nathan is building up to the dramatic reveal that what Elena thinks she knows about history is, in fact, not true. The entire dialogue at this part of the scene is:

> Elena: Are you sure you wanna be defiling your ancestor's remains like that?
>
> Nathan: You make it sound so dirty. Besides, I thought you didn't believe me.
>
> Elena: Well, I did do my research. And apparently, Francis Drake didn't have
>   any children.
>
> Nathan: Well, history can be wrong, you know. For example - you can't defile an empty coffin.

At this point, Elena believes that the coffin contains the remains of Sir Francis Drake, whom Nathan claims to be descended from. Elena's research has indicated that Drake has no children, so she's accusing Nathan of lying. His response is that "history can be wrong", in other words, history's claim that Drake has no children is incorrect.

To make his point, he then opens the coffin. If history were right, and the coffin did contain Drake's remains as Elena believes, than Nathan is about to defile those remains by breaking it open. However, "history is wrong" -- the coffin does not contain a body, and thus, opening an empty coffin isn't defiling anyone.

Basically, Nathan's comment is just a smart-ass way of saying "you think you know all these things -- that Drake is in this coffin, that Drake had no children -- but what you think you know isn't necessarily the truth."